# SwiftMailer 'ErrorException' with message 'fopen(/tmp/...) failed to open stream: Permission denied'

Tags: php, laravel, shared-hosting, swiftmailer

I've deployed a `laravel` app on a `cpanel` `shared host`.

When sending email usign `Mail` class, the following error occurs randomly. (sometimes the mail is sent but sometimes the error occurs)

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'fopen(/tmp/e19839f1a2d67e4ab7c83a5951c31bfd/body): failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /home/ekbatana/laravel4/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/KeyCache/DiskKeyCache.php:300
```

I contacted the host support they said I need to change the default temporary directory.

In SwiftMailer package `lib/preferences.php` a variable called `$tmp` is set to `getenv('TMPDIR')` and a comment in the file says that:

```
// You can override the default temporary directory by setting the TMPDIR environment variable.
```

I tried to set the `TMPDIR` in different ways

1) .htaccess: `SetEnv   TMPDIR  /home/.../laravel4/app/storage/my_temp`

2) in `app/start/global.php` and also in `App::before` callback function using `php putenv` function

3) in `lib/preferences.php` before the line that $temp is set using `php putenv` function

but non of them changes the path to the file that is opened and causes `failed to open stream: Permission denied` error

the following is the `swiftmailer/lib/preferences.php`

```
<?php

/****************************************************************************/
/*                                                                          */
/* YOU MAY WISH TO MODIFY OR REMOVE THE FOLLOWING LINES WHICH SET DEFAULTS  */
/*                                                                          */
/****************************************************************************/

$preferences = Swift_Preferences::getInstance();

// Sets the default charset so that setCharset() is not needed elsewhere
$preferences->setCharset('utf-8');

// Without these lines the default caching mechanism is "array" but this uses a lot of memory.
// If possible, use a disk cache to enable attaching large attachments etc.
// You can override the default temporary directory by setting the TMPDIR environment variable.

// The @ operator in front of is_writable calls is to avoid PHP warnings
// when using open_basedir
$tmp = getenv('TMPDIR');
if ($tmp && @is_writable($tmp)) {
    $preferences
        ->setTempDir($tmp)
        ->setCacheType('disk');
} elseif (function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir') && @is_writable(sys_get_temp_dir())) {
    $preferences
        ->setTempDir(sys_get_temp_dir())
        ->setCacheType('disk');
}

// this should only be done when Swiftmailer won't use the native QP content encoder
// see mime_deps.php
if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.7', '<')) {
    $preferences->setQPDotEscape(false);
}
```

Comment: Did the hosting provider tell you to which directory you need to change you temporary directory?

Comment: @lowerends no, but the new temp directory's permission is 755

Comment: Can you debug what `TMPDIR` is currently set at? You could use `dd($_ENV['TMPDIR'])` for that.

Comment: @lowerends just before the $tmep assignment, it is the value that i've set

Comment: the problem is that the `is_writable` returns `false`, the directory permission is 0755 and even when i set it to 0777 `is_writable` still returns `false` and causes the `elseif` block executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether the directory is writable by the process trying to write to the directory. You can verify which user and group is used by your process by executing:

```
<?php
    echo getmyuid().':'.getmygid();
?>
```

This will give you something like `user:group`. Then you need to `chown` the directory to write to with:

```
chown -R user:group writable_directory/
```